# High quality GIF Compression from images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I am having an issue with my GIFS. I have strung together two images as an animation in Photoshop, both high quality off the bat (2000 x 3000 px), I know when I compress into a moving GIF it's going to be slightly lower quality, which is fine as the intended output is 300 x 500 px. My issue is with the blockiness of the background. The images are shot on a grey studio backdrop, and whilst the subject is not blocky in any way, the background becomes heavily pixelated and colour is distorted. I know what I'm doing with settings, dithers and colours etc, so my question is:

Is there are better methodology to creating a high quality GIF without the above issue?

Comment: Are you animating the entire 2000x3000 pixels or just a small area? limiting the number of changes against the background allows the gif format to better compress large fields of color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subject matter is photographic in nature, as your sounds to be, then there really is no such thing as 'high quality GIF'.

GIFs have an extremely limited color palette of only 256 colors. With the possible exception of a pure black and white photo, it will degrade the quality of most any photo. You can limit it with dithering and such, but it will always be of a lower quality than your source file.

Beyond that, post a sample of what you have and maybe we can give some specific pointers that apply to your particular image.